# ffmpeg code (API)

Tags: api, ffmpeg

I started to deal with ffmpeg API ( not the command prompt ) to build a movie editor, and I'm trying to find a good tutorial about how to extract keyframes from video, but I didn't find it.

1. Someone did it before and can write the code here?
2. Someone has a good tutorial about ffmpeg API?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your demuxing loop, check for the `AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY` flag in `AVPacket::flags` after calling `av_read_frame()` with your `AVFormatContext` and confirming the read packet is from the correct stream of the input. Example:

```
AVPacket packet;

if (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) < 0) {
    break;
}

if (videoStream/* e.g. 0 or 1 */ == packet.stream_index) {
    if (packet.flags & AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY) { //do something
```

Note that, in my experience, you sometimes need to decode up to 2 keyframes before the desired frame in order to produce a good picture.

See the `doc/examples` directory in the ffmpeg distribution for some API usage examples, e.g. `demuxing_decoding.c`. You can also reference `ffmpeg.c` (the source of the famous CLI) if you are brave and/or have a good IDE.

Comment: Also make sure you stop looking for keyframes if you decode N frames and did not find any. There are poorly-encoded movies which have only one keyframe, so when looking for first five keyframes you may end up reading the whole movie.